# MySQL str_to_date()

Tags: mysql

I am running into an issue trying to format a date column from looking like this:  `05-JUN-15` to the standard MYSQL format. What I tried to do was:

```
UPDATE sp_building_headcount
    set `ATTENDANCE_LOCALDATE` = str_to_date(`ATTENDANCE_LOCALDATE`,'%d-%b-%y')
```

I thought I selected the right date format but I am getting this error: `Incorrect datetime value: '05-JUN-15' for function str_to_date`

What would be the correct date/time format?

Comment: You should do this as part of a two step process: Once to normalize the date formatting, another pass to set the column to `DATE` type. If you have clean data this is easy. If it's potentially dirty (e.g. human edited, irregular formatting) you may need to create a conversion column to find any mistakes.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the tip! this is what i was looking for.

Comment: To anyone who is curious the way to do this is to use lower() which converts the string to all lowercase characters and then to run str_to_date(columnanme, %d-%B-%y') @tadman thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you've got a solid, working solution you can always add a self-answer with the details. This helps others in the same jam. That someone might even be you in the future when this problem crops up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found thanks to @tadman (Gotta give credit where credit is due) was to to first use lower() to convert it from `05-JUN-15` to `05-jun-15`. 
Example of lower():

```
UPDATE sp_building_headcount

set `ATTENDANCE_LOCALDATE` = LOWER(`ATTENDANCE_LOCALDATE`)
```

This then worked with:

```
UPDATE sp_building_headcount
    set `ATTENDANCE_LOCALDATE` = str_to_date(`ATTENDANCE_LOCALDATE`,'%d-%b-%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is `05-JUN-15`. Your `str_to_date` format is `%d/%B/%y`, i.e. `05/Jun/15`. Your data doesn't match the format, both where the separators are concerned and the capitalization of the month. The data must fit the format you tell MySQL it's in.